# Drop existing database and recreate the schema in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

is there any way to recreate the schema in hibernate? `create` property of `hbm2ddl` creates the new tables, `update` property updates the schema. But I want to drop the first i.e. existing database and recreate it. I need to do this because of hibernate's issue i.e. when we change the type of column, it creates new column instead of changing existing. So as the solution, I have to drop the schema manually and then deploy my application. Can I do this dropping and recreating process from application itself as it's in liquibase?

Comment: Why does `create` not work for you?  For me, it drops all the tables, then creates new ones.  How is your behaviour different?

Comment: @DavidWallace, it worked for me too, I just tried. But can you just post this as an answer so I can choose it as right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `create` as the value of `hbm2ddl`.  This will drop the old tables as well as creating new ones.

Comment: Same as I wanted, this will drop existing schema and create new one. Once it's done, we can change the property back to `update` on next deployment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

delete the old schema. Run the server/program it will create all schemas for you again.

Comment: This will create the schema but only if it doesn't exist so I'll have to manually delete the schema from db server while I wanted to delete from my application itself. `create` works for that.